# can't understand routing in node/express4

Tags: node.js, express, express-4

Please, help to clear up the routing issue:

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var router = express.Router();

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// data storage in memory
var widgets = [
  {id: 1,
   name: 'My special widget',
   price: 100.00,
   descr: 'A widget beyond price'},
];

// routes

app.use(router);

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});

router.get('/widgets', function(req, res) {
  res.send(widgets);
});

router.post('/widgets/add', function(req, res) {
  var indx = widgets.length + 1;
  widgets[widgets.length] = {  id: indx,
                               name: req.body.widgetname,
                               price: parseFloat(req.body.widgetprice),
                               descr: req.body.widgetdesc
                            };
  console.log('added ' + widgets[indx - 1]);
  res.send('Widget ' + req.body.widgetname + ' added with id ' + indx);  
});

router.get('/widgets/:id', function(req, res) {
  var indx = parseInt(req.params.id) - 1;
  if (!widgets[indx]) {
    res.send('There is no widget with id of ' + req.params.id);
  } else {
    res.send(widgets[indx]);
  }
});

router.put('/widgets/:id/update', function(req, res) {
  var indx = req.params.id - 1;
  widgets[indx] = {id: indx,
                   name: req.body.widgetname,
                   price: parseFloat(req.body.widgetprice),
                   descr: req.body.widgetdesc};
  console.log(widgets[indx]);
  res.send('updated ' + req.params.id);
});

router.delete('/widgets/:id/delete', function(req, res) {
  var indx = req.params.id - 1;
  delete widgets[indx];
  console.log('deleted ' + req.params.id);
  res.send('deleted ' + req.params.id);  
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

I have 3 html files in VIEWS folder:
1 - index

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Widgets</title>
</head>
<body>

 <form action="/widgets/add" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  
  <p>Widget name:<input type="text" name="widgetname" id="widgetname" size="25" required /></p>

  <p>Widget price:<input type="text" name="widgetprice" id="widgetprice" size="25" required
   pattern="^\$?([0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{3},)*[0-9]{3}|[0-9]+)(.[0-9][0-9])?$" /></p>

  <p>Widget description: <br/> <textarea name="widgetdesc" id="widgetdesc" cols="20"
   rows="5">Describe widget</textarea></p>
  <p>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
   <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
  </p>

 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

2 - update

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Widgets</title>
</head>
<body>

 <form method="POST" action="/widgets/1/update" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  
  <p>Widget name:<input type="text" name="widgetname" id="widgetname" size="25" value="Me special widget" required /></p>

  <p>Widget price:<input type="text" name="widgetprice" id="widgetprice" size="25" required
   pattern="^\$?([0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{3},)*[0-9]{3}|[0-9]+)(.[0-9][0-9])?$" value="100.00" /></p>

  <p>Widget description: <br/> <textarea name="widgetdesc" id="widgetdesc" cols="20"
   rows="5">A widget beyond price</textarea></p>

  <input type="hidden" value="put" name="_method" />

  <p>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
   <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
  </p>

 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

3 - delete

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Widgets</title>
</head>
<body>
 <p>Are you sure you want to delete widget?</p>
 
 <form method="POST" action="/widgets/1/delete" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  
  <input type="hidden" value="delete" name="_method" />
  
  <p>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Delete Widget" />
  </p>

 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

The trouble is that PUT and DELETE show error and I can not undersatnd what should I do in order to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with this example. I'll address them from most to least important.

## Method confusion

REST, or **RE**presentational **S**tate **T**ransfer, defines what are called HTTP verbs with different purposes.

- GET: Fetches a resource
- POST: Creates a resource
- PUT: Overwrites a resource
- PATCH: Partially modifies a resource
- DELETE: Removes a resource
- And some others

One thing to note is that in express routers a GET request will not be matched by a POST URL handler even if the URL is the same. Even though the URL is the same, the action is different.

So the reason you are seeing a 404 error when you try to POST to `/widgets/1/update` is because **you did not define a POST handler, you defined a PUT handler**.

## Improper REST URLs

Because you can have multiple actions for the same URL, a sort of standard has arisen. Since URLs are designed to refer to resources, not actions, try to keep action words out of the URL.

For example. Instead of having a PUT handler for `/widgets/1/update`, just do a PUT handler for `/widgets/1`. The fact that you're updating is already obvious because you're doing a PUT request.

In the same way, make a DELETE handler for `/widgets/1` instead of `/widgets/1/delete`.

Keep in mind that this will not collide with a GET or DELETE handler for `/widgets/1` because the verb is different.

The POST is a bit different. Instead of POST `/widgets/add`, use POST `/widgets`.

To picture this, if you were to verbalize what you want to do:

**Create** a record in **widgets**

or

**POST** to **/widgets**

The "add" or "create" is already obvious because it is a POST request.

## Code order

This is a small gripe. You are `.use()`ing the router before you actually define the routes. This works because of how javascript handles object variables, but it looks backwards.

## Understanding Express

`app` in your code can handle `.post()`, `.get()`, etc. There is no reason to construct and use a router in your code.

`express.Router()` is used when you want to mount a whole bunch of paths on a partial URL or keep a group of URLs mentally seperate For example:

```
var app = express()
var apiRoutes = require("./api-router")
var frontendRoutes = require("./frontend-router")

app.use("/api", apiRoutes)
app.use(frontendRoutes)
```